# PHP image upload spot error

Tags: php

I am  new to PHP and I have been  trying to make an image Uploader with PHP, but I have a problem, it only uploads 3 pictures then it stops and I don't know why it is so.

This is the HTML Code

```
<?php

require ('script.php');
$classObj = new news ;
$classObj->dbcon();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test drive</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username"></input>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="firstname"></input>
    <input type="file" name="file"></input>
    <input type="submit" name="submit"></input>

</form>
<?php $classObj->sent(); ?>

</body>
</html
```

This is the PHP Code

```
function upload(){
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $this->img_name = $_FILES['img']['name'];
        $this->img_size = $_FILES['img']['size'];
        $this->img_tmpname = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'];
        $this->img_path = basename($this->img_name);
        $this->img_ext = $_FILES['img']['type'];
         $this->img_dir = 'upload/'.$this->img_path;
           if ($this->img_ext != "jpg" || $this->img_ext != "JPG" ||$this->img_ext != "png" ||$this->img_ext != "PNG" ||$this->img_ext != "JPEG" ||$this->img_ext != "jpeg" ) {
        if (file_exists("$this->img_dir")) {
            echo "<p> sorry file exist</p>";
            exit();
        }else{
             move_uploaded_file( $this->img_tmpname, $this->img_dir);
            echo '<p>succesfull</p>';
            echo $_FILES['img']['size'];
            header("location:$this->img_dir");
        }
    }else{
        echo "invalid pics";
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: where do you call the php upload function?

Comment: Seriously you uploaded 3 images? your input file name is "file" and your are using $_FILES['img']['name'] in your code. How is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You have a miss match of name. Change the name of the field to img because you are calling it's value in your PHP script.

```
<input type="file" name="img"></input>
```